# Mathematica function to calculate equivalent NormalDistribution from a WeibullDistribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions

I have a `WeibullDistribution` with mean 12.0 and standard deviation 3.2.
Is there any built-in *Mathematica* function that calculates an equivalent `NormalDistribution` from the `WeibullDistribution`?  Additionally, how do you use *Mathematica* to find a `WeibullDistribution` having a given mean and standard deviation?

Comment: Whoever voted the question down:  This is a fine question and should be answered.  The true question is how to find the "equivalent" parameters for a Weibull and a Normal distribution, given that the parameterization of a Weibull is *not* in the form of mean and variance (or standard deviation).

Comment: I didn't vote, but it really is not clear what this means. If you *know* the mean/sd the *equivalent* would be just the normal distribution with the same mean/sd.  LeoRon7,  can you edit the question to be more clear? Perhaps you know the weibull parameters and want the mean/sd, which would be essentially the inverse of the answer you got.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork, well if that's the question, it belongs on math.stackexchange imo...

Comment: There is no equivalent Normal distribution to match your Weibull distribution. For starters, the Weibull has a strictly positive domain of support and is skewed, whereas the Normal is defined on the real line and is symmetrical.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork the downvote was mine and it was because it is not clear what "equivalent" means in the sense of two different distributions. What should one do about the higher moments? I upvoted your answer, but objectively one cannot be sure that it answers the question. OP also asks for a built-in function, for which I do not understand the motivation at all. It did not seem to me that the question met the threshold of closure, so I thought a downvote was the best way to indicate that it seems poorly posed. I will gladly retract it if the question is improved.

Comment: @OleksandrR:  As you may know, "sufficient statistics" for a distribution are statistics that define it completely.  If I give you the mean and variance (or standard deviation), you know everything possibly about a `NormalDistribution`.  Given that the poser mentioned just mean and standard deviation, it seemed logical (though I confirmed) that he meant just those statistics.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork but maybe one should use the sum of two or more normal distributions to account for the skewness of this particular Weibull distribution? Maybe it sounds overcomplicated or unnecessary to you, and in fairness to your answer, you have given an appropriate caveat. Nonetheless, the question does not rule out this possibility by any means (or it did not until you edited it--but I don't know what motivated this edit).

Comment: @OleksandrR.  I believe the question *does* rule out the possibility of "the sum of two or more normal distributions" when it states "*an* equivalent normal distribution."

Comment: @DavidG.Stork if your answer is accepted then I will remove the downvote on the question. But it seems unproductive for us to continue to debate whether it should be read as "*an* equivalent normal distribution" or "an *equivalent* normal distribution".

Comment: I have also downvoted this, because the first question is confusing and has no proper answer. The second question is perfectly respectable.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If by "equivalent" you mean having the same mean and standard deviation:

```
NormalDistribution[12, 3.2]
```

What is the relationship between the mean and variance of a Weibull distribution and its parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$?

```
Mean[WeibullDistribution[α, β]]
```

$\beta  \Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)$

```
Variance[WeibullDistribution[α, β]]
```

$\beta ^2 \left(\Gamma \left(1+\frac{2}{\alpha }\right)-\Gamma \left(1+\frac{1}{\alpha}\right)^2\right)$

So, if you are given the mean and variance of a Weibull distribution, you must solve (numerically) for $\alpha$ and $\beta$:

```
FindRoot[{β Gamma[1 + 1/α] == 12, 
  β^2 (-Gamma[1 + 1/α]^2 + Gamma[1 + 2/α]) == 3.2*3.2}, 
 {{α, 5}, {β, 10}}]
```

$\{\alpha \to 4.23053,\beta \to 13.1967\}$

(Note that the desired *variance* is the square of the standard deviation.)

So here is a `NormalDistribution` and a `WeibullDistribution` having the same means and standard deviations:

```
Plot[{PDF[WeibullDistribution[4.23053, 13.1967], x], 
  PDF[NormalDistribution[12, 3.2], x]}, 
  {x, 0, 20}]
```

[image]

Comment: The diagram illustrates neatly that the two distributions are not equivalent ... and thus too that the OP's first question should be dropped or modified, because there is NO equivalent Normal distribution. David's answer above addresses the OP's second question very nicely. However, perhaps the OP should ponder why he is only making use of the first 2 (sample?) moments as the basis to fit his Weibull pdf ... and ignoring higher moments that may readily be available.